# Unable to load the specified metadata resource Release vs Debug build

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've been scratching my head for hours with a peculiar issue in Entity Framework.

The following questions are **not** duplicates since their answers do not help me:

- [MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689355/metadataexception-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)
- [Entity Framework - Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339335/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)
- [Unable to load the specified metadata resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648212/unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource)

I have an `aspnet core` mvc app (`v1.1`) that references a `.NET Framework 4.7` project (the [Data Access Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)) with `Entity Framework 6.1.3` installed as a NuGet package.

I'm using the designer so I have an `.edmx` file.
I'm getting the following exception thrown at my face in runtime:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

And I have the following connectionstring:

```
metadata=res://*/MyContext.csdl|res://*/MyContext.ssdl|res://*/MyContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

The thing is, when running in a `Debug` build, the application runs without any problems. However when running in a `Release` build, the exception gets thrown. But if I disable `optimize code` on the project with the `.edmx` file, the exception is **not** thrown anymore.

I've even looked in the [Entity Framework source code.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/6.1.3/src/EntityFramework/Core/Metadata/Edm/MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.cs) You can see from the Stacktrace, that this exception gets thrown at line `170`, because `loaders.Count == 0`. I don't understand why the resources can't be loaded from the assembly in a `Release` build, while it works in a `Debug` build.

**EDIT** I just installed a trial version of Reflector to inspect the assembly. So when looking into the `.dll` file that has been built with the Debug configuration, I can clearly see the 3 resource files embedded. However, in the assembly that has been built with a Release configuration, oddly the resource files are missing!

Comment: I'm encountering a very similar problem, and my setup is similar to yours - full framework entity framework project, referenced by .net core mvc app. If I run my project in VS, or deploy it to Azure, all is good. If I use "dotnet run" from the command line, I would occasionally get this error. Doing a clean and rebuild in VS has until now got rid of it. But now on just one of my 2 dev machines this happens every time using "dotnet run" but not at all in VS! Will continue digging, but please do update this is you find anything further.

Comment: Just as a follow up. I have confirmed what you have observed - the resources are not being included in the Entities assembly when I build the project using dotnet run. Maybe it is the same underlying issue. Thanks for your post anyway - I have got around it by just running the .exe generated by VS rather than using dotnet run (which insists on rebuilding the Entities assembly).

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the dotnet CLI: see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6812). It's unfortunate that Microsoft does not respond to this.

Comment: I am also having this problem. I will try to remember to answer here when i solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround for this problem.

I'm targeting a .net core 3.1 linux container with a legacy project using an EDMX.
Migration of the whole EDMX in code first will take a lot of time so I had to find a solution to make it work in Azure.

Problem is that a dotnet cli command like `dotnet publish` does not embed csdl, msl, or ssdl files see [issues #8932](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8932).
So do not embed it in the output assembly. This is partially explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547289/entity-framework-metadata-artifact-not-embeded-when-using-xbuild-and-mono).

1. First change the "Metadata artifact processing" property in the "Conceptual Entity Model" of the EDMX from "Embeded in Output Assembly" to "Copy to output directory" [this picture show you how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg0BL.png).

Note that you need to open the EDMX file (double click), since a single click will show you the property of the file.

2. copy the csdl, msl, and ssdl files for publishing. I do that with a PostBuild event in the csproj file. Like this :

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix'" Command="echo *** cp -a $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)* $(TargetDir)" />
    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Unix'" Command="cp -a $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)* $(TargetDir)" />

    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Unix'" Command="echo *** copy /Y $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)* $(TargetDir)" />
    <Exec Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Unix'" Command="copy /Y $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)* $(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

Note that you'll have to adapt the copy command paths to match your solution (for example if your EDMX project is located in a sub-project).

3. Finally change your connection string to a non embeded metadata ([see doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings)).

From

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=[...]"
```

To

```
connectionString="metadata=/app;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=[...]"
```

Since the folder change upon release/debug/publish I've created this small function in my application to change the connection string :

```
private string EntityConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder csb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        ProviderConnectionString = connectionString,
        Metadata = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    };
    csb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    return csb.ConnectionString;
}
```

Just provide the connection string in the classical non EDMX format to the connectionString parameter of the function. ie :

```
data source=[...];initial catalog=EntityframeworkTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me, For those who's EMX editor isn't working just make the following change to the XML file

    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="CopyToOutputDirectory" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>